# Unable to start docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, sendy

I'm trying to configure sendy to run on docker-compose. I'm getting this error when running `docker-compose up`

#### error

```sh
Building sendy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 126, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1070, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1066, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 615, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 362, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1147, in build
compose.service.BuildError: (<Service: sendy>, {'message': 'failed to parse Dockerfile: file with no instructions'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 78, in main
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str
[83327] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.7"

# Volumes for persisted data.
volumes: 
  data_sendy:
    labels: 
      co.sendy.description: "Data volume for Sendy Database."

# Secret files so they're not exposed via 'docker inspect'
secrets:
  db_password:
    file: secrets/db_password.txt
  db_root_password:
    file: secrets/db_root_password.txt      

services:
  # Database: MySQL
  db_sendy:
    hostname: db_sendy
    container_name: db_sendy
    image: mysql:5.6
    env_file: 
      - sendy.env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_root_password
    secrets:
      - db_root_password
      - db_password      
    volumes: 
      - data_sendy:/var/lib/mysql

  # WebApp: Apache2+PHP+Sendy
  sendy:
    hostname: sendy
    container_name: sendy
    depends_on: 
      - db_sendy
    image: bubbajames/sendy:4.1
    build: 
      context: .
      # Uncomment to enabled XDEBUG build
      # target: debug
    env_file: 
      - sendy.env
    secrets:
      - db_password 
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  # Load Balancer: HAProxy
  load-balancer:
    hostname: lb_sendy
    container_name: lb_sendy
    image: lb_sendy
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: haproxy/Dockerfile   
    env_file: 
      - sendy.env      
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the directory where that docker-compose file exists, is there a Dockerfile specifically called "**Dockerfile**"?

Under your **sendy** service, you have the context as the current directory, but no Dockerfile specified. By default, it will look for a file called "Dockerfile" at that location.